# Is my CPU 32 bits or 64 bits?

Tags: cpu

The operating system on my machine is Windows 7 32bit.

[image]

Although Windows lists as 32 bits, but does also mean my CPU is 32 bits? If not how could I find out what my CPU is?

[image]

Comment: Check the specification page for your CPU to answer this question.

Comment: All CPUs from AMD from Opteron/Athlon 64 and Intel Pentium 4 Prescott and later supports EM64T, or x86_64 instruction set except some Atom CPUs. You don't need to worry about 64-bit support in CPUs in around 10 years back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The T6600 is a 64 bit CPU which means you can use it to run either the 32-bit or the 64-bit version of Windows. Its [specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/37255/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6600-2M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) say:

> Instruction Set:   64-bit

Answer (score 6):

Although your Windows is a 32-bit installation your CPU is capable of running a 64-bit operating system. This support is indicated by the existance of the `Yes` value for the `Intel® 64` product feature on the [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T6600](http://ark.intel.com/products/37255/intel-core2-duo-processor-t6600-2m-cache-2_20-ghz-800-mhz-fsb#EM64) 
on the specification page within the `Advanced Technologies` section

Comment: it is not that my CPU Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E6600 , it is T6600

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/fr/products/37255/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6600-2M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Answer (score 4):

The important "Instructions" flag that CPU-Z shows here is `EM64T`, which is the extension of Intel CPU's to execute 64 Bit commands (along with 32 Bit, which are still possible). On an AMD CPU the according flag would be `x86-64`.

What the Windows "system type" displays is the actual word width that is currently used. In your case 32 Bit.

**Conclusion:** your CPU is able to run 64 Bit Windows and 32 Bit Windows (what you have). If you want to run 64 Bit programs, you need 64 Bit Windows (which still can run 32 Bit applications). If you have a Windows 64Bit setup DVD/image or know someone that has one, you can install Windows 64 Bit with the key from your 32 Bit Windows (they are interchangable between 32 and 64 bit, as long as the key itself is valid and used within its license restictions). Backup you data, however, since upgrading 32 to 64 Bit is not possible (at least not straightforward), only a fresh install is possible when switching the architecture.